# How do you conduct remote usability tests on mobile for your web app?

Tags: usability, mobile, mobile-web, testing

Not sure if this is possible, but I'm looking for a solution similar to [Lookback](http://lookback.io/) but specifically for web apps? I realise [a similar question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29959/screen-video-capturing-usability-test-on-mobile/29984#29984) has been asked before, but I'm looking to find a solution which caters for remote users.

The solution needs to:

- Records video sessions of 5-10m
- Ability for the users to use their own phone, viewing the web app via a web browser
- Work remotely
- Minimal effort from the users' part in terms of installing software
- Target specific users (i.e ones we've found ourselves)

Nice to have:

- Records voice
- Records taps and gestures

We could, of course, simply use something like Google Hangouts on laptops and ask the users to resize their screens for mobile, but that's not an ideal solution.

Comment: You've put web testing, then stated users must have their own phones...

Comment: @UXfrom12 Yes, it's a web app where certain people may use the app on their phones, via a browser. I've updated the OP to make that more clear, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need a combination of tools.

InVision will allow users to see your prototyped application, unless you have it on a test server as a test app, then this step isn't required.

Hotjar allows you to record sessions, although I doubt it does recording of voice.

As they're remote users it's more important that you set-up your test scenario, so the recording makes sense and the post-test questionnaire asks the right questions.

Comment: Hotjar might be a good idea... run the session via Hangouts, record the audio as we conduct the test, and then have the video recording via HotJar as a reference. I'll look into that, thanks @UXfrom12